# Security for R Shiny App secrets on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, security, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am using persistent data storage with a deployed app on shinyapps.io. I am reading and writing to an external SQL db. This app will be open to public, but data saved will be private.

What is the best/most secure way to store the private api keys for the db on the shinyapps.io server?

Config file?
.renviron?

Comment: I suggest environment variables, since should be controllable in the interface governing the app instance (disclaimer: I do not use shinyapps.io, but I use Posit's "Connect" server all the time, which provides very similar capabilities). An advantage to envvars over files is that you are able to update the keys without having to redeploy the application; while that is not necessarily onerous, it is certainly inconvenient.